# Grizzly Server aborted the SSL handshake

Tags: maven, curl, ssl, safari, grizzly

I have a questions about using SSL with self-signed certificate.
I was using this example here http://people.apache.org/~gmazza/restexamples/https-clientserver-grizzly

The unit test works perfectly. However, if I started grizzly server, and try to use curl to get the resources, I got errors like:

```
curl -v https://localhost:8443/api/v1/hello
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7ff69b004400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7ff69b004400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8443 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying fe80::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

I already add the certificate to the system key chains with always trusted for all categories. Still, no browser can get the resource. Here is the error message I got from Chrome.

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

ADD:

For curl, I was generating java keystore and cert using key tool

```
keytool  -genkey -keystore ./keystore_server -alias serverKey -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Jersey, O=Sun Microsystem, L=Prague, ST=Czech Republic, C=CZ"  
keytool -export -alias serverKey -rfc -keystore ./keystore_server > ./server.cert
openssl x509 -in server.cert -inform PEM -text -out server.pem
```

I then ran

```
curl -E server.pem -v https://localhost:8443/api/v1/hello -u "username:password"
```

However, I got same error as before.

For browsers, I have now gotten it worked for Firefox and Chrome. However, I am still having trouble with Safari. I got error message saying that Safari cannot open the page because safari cannot establish a secure connection to the server.Anyone has any idea how can I make safari happy?

Comment: just a wild guess, may be the key/cert files are visible only for unit tests, they are located in test/resources not in the main/resources. If it's not the case - pls. share the maven project so we can double check.

Comment: The file is actually under the same directory as the pom.xml. Same structure as this example here :https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/https-clientserver-grizzly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if I started grizzly server, and try to use curl to get the resources, I got errors like...

cURL does not use the operating system's keychain. The exception to the rule is *if* cURL is built against `SecureTransport` for iOS or OS X. See [curl.1 the man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and the `-E` or `--cert` option. And even in that case, its not for trusted anchors.

If you have a particular CA you would like to use to certify the server, then you should specify it with the `--cacert` option. You can also specify the [`cacert.pem`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) bundle with this option. See [curl.1 the man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

---

> Chrome ... Error code: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

This is a different issue. Chrome uses the operating system's keystore. See the Chromium Projects' [Root Certificate Policy](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy).

To fix it, you might want to look at [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

It might be a good idea to post the certificate with your question. Use the following to generate it (assuming its PEM encoded):

```
openssl x509 -in <cert> -inform PEM -text -noout
```

---

> Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

Others have probably experienced the issue, too.

Comment: I have now gotten it worked for Firefox and Chrome. However, I am still having trouble with Safari. I got error message saying that Safari cannot open the page because safari cannot establish a secure connection to the server. Do you have any idea how can I make safari happy?